# Alternative for Facebook API without using "publish_actions" to publish a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

as per facebook's documentation they will be removing "publish_actions" permissions after August 1, 2018. As an alternative they have suggested to use Share Dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog , But share dialog doesn't serve my purpose as previously I was publishing photos to users timeline from my plugin using "publish_actions" adding that photo a any specific album present on user's account, however Share Dialog is now allowing me only to share link of the photo which gives user different exeprience. Is there an alternative way to post photo to any of the user's album without using "publish_actions" permission.
TIA

Ruby

Comment: i assume there will be no alternative, no. you can only wait though. all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 2):

Take look on publish_groups.

"The **publish_actions** permission is deprecated in Graph API v3.0. Apps can still post stories via mediated experiences like the Facebook Share Dialog on the web, or the Share Sheets for iOS and Android. Apps can publish to groups through the **publish_groups** permission, which requires an app go through review."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/faqs/?fragment=graph-api-3-0

section: 
"*My app uses the user_managed_groups permission. Is it affected by v3.0?*"

Hope this helps

Comment: So how do you post to a users feed without the share dialog? As this would make things very inconvenient for me without this ability.

Comment: @hehe,  publish_groups permission refers only to publishing to groups, not to user timeline. Also, in their official docs for Group API it is mentioned  'publish_to_group' and  'groups_access_member_info', which differs from permissions mentioned for Graph API v3.0. So look like they are pretty unclear still about this.